# C declaration confusion

Tags: c++, c, pointers, reference, function-definition

What is the difference (if any) between these two parameter declarations and calling methods?

#1:

```
void MyFunction(MyStruct& msParam)
{
.....
}

MyStruct ms;

MyFunction(ms);
```

And #2:

```
void MyFunction(MyStruct* msParam)
{
.....
}

MyStruct ms;

MyFunction(&ms);
```

They both seem to pass a pointer to the variable 'ms' so I'm guessing that functionally they are the same and equally efficient but is one style preferred for some occasions?

Comment: The first case at least is not C code. The function has a reference arg which is valid for C++ but not C.

Answer (score 2):

Such a function declaration

```
void MyFunction(MyStruct& msParam) { ..... }
```

is not a valid C declaration.

It can be a valid C++ function declaration where the parameter means a reference to an object of the type MyStruct.

This function declaration

```
void MyFunction(MyStruct* msParam) { ..... }
```

is a valid C and C++ function declaration where the parameter has pointer type to an object of the type MyStruct.

So to call the function you need to apply the operator & to the passed object to get a pointer to the object.

```
MyStruct ms;

MyFunction(&ms);
```

So the functions are not the same.

The first function deals with an object of the type `MyStruct` while the second function deals with the pointer type `MyStruct *`.

Comment: Ah I see! I spotted it in a declaration in somebody elses code but now I've checked it is indeed C++. Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

```
void MyFunction(MyStruct& msParam)
{
.....
}
```

The first declaration is used in C++, because C++ is Object Oriented. So the code -

MyStruct ms;
MyFunction(ms);

Refer a reference of MyStruct object.

Whereas,

```
void MyFunction(MyStruct* msParam)
```

{
.....
}

MyStruct ms;

MyFunction(&ms);

Can be used in C and C++ both, because here we are passing a reference and excepting pointer to MyStruct.